# Validation in SQL Server Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need a stored procedure which accepts 4 parameters. When I pass these 4 parameter values same my stored procedure should return false else it should return true.

I am new to stored procedure.

Suppose when I pass `'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'` as parameters to my stored procedure, my stored procedure should return false else true

Comment: Good. It sounds like you have a spec. So now you need to make an attempt and come back here with the actual problems you have in implementing that spec.

Comment: As I said I am new to stored procedure, Now i don't have time to learn stored procedures and implement that. If u understand my question Please do needful.

Comment: And I'm not here to do your entire job for you. There is *plenty* of documentation and *plenty* of tutorials out there for you to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create procedure test_parameters
    @a varchar(10),@b varchar(10),@c varchar(10),@d varchar(10)

as
     begin
          select case when @a=@b and @b=@c and @c=@d then 'False' else 'TRUE' 
     end
end

 exec test_parameters @a='test',@b='test',@c='test',@d='test'
```

--`Returns FALSE`